# WaitForSingleObject waits infinitely for thread terminate

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have two functions:

```
Fl_Thread n_create_thread(Fl_Thread &t, void *(*f) (void *), void *p) 
{
    return t = (Fl_Thread)_beginthread((void(__cdecl *)(void *))f, 0, p);    
}

void n_wait_end_thread(Fl_Thread t) 
{
    WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)t, INFINITE);    
}
```

Create thread, give pointer to thread function, but if I wait to terminate thread by WaitForSingleObject, it hangs and can't stop waiting.

Comment: You might want to check the return value of _beginthread to see if it's really a valid handle.

Comment: Are you sure that `f()` is actually exiting?

Comment: Also keep in mind that `_endthread()`, which is called when a `_beginthread()` thread terminates, *closes the thread handle*, so the wait could fail.

Comment: BTW, you should not be type-casting `f` at all when passing it to `_beginthread()`: `_beginthread(f, ...);`  If the compiler fails because `f` is the wrong signature, that is a real error that can cause real runtime problems, so a type-cast would simply hide that. Usually (not always) when you have to type-cast something, you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW, why does `n_create_thread()` have both an `Fl_Thread` return value and an `Fl_Thread` reference parameter? What is the purpose of the parameter?  It is not being used.  If it is an output parameter, you should probably be doing this: `t = (Fl_Thread) _beginthread(...); return t;`

Comment: [A function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).

Comment: Problem was in f(), Can't go to Fl::lock() (FLTK library) when in main thread is main_win->hide(),is OK when I move main_win->hide() after n_wait_end_thread

Answer (score 1):

Your thread handle could be invalid when you wait on it - use `_beginthreadex` instead - [see the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx):

> It's safer to use _beginthreadex than _beginthread. If the thread
>   that's generated by _beginthread exits quickly, the handle that's
>   returned to the caller of _beginthread might be invalid or point to
>   another thread. However, the handle that's returned by _beginthreadex
>   has to be closed by the caller of _beginthreadex, so it is guaranteed
>   to be a valid handle if _beginthreadex did not return an error.